# Preventing URL SQL Injection

Tags: sql, url, code-injection

I want to know the best way to prevent or void SQL Injection or URL's.

For example, www.mysite.com/profile.php?id=18.
This kind of site (if the MySQL_Error is enable) is vulnerable to Injections.
How can i prevent it? mysql_real_escape_string is going to be deprecate, so it's gonna be useless soon.

I tried htmlspecialchars() but it doesn't work on URL's.

Comment: Have you tried bound parameters (aka. "bind variables")?

Comment: What do you mean bound parameters/variables? Not english, sorry.

Comment: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/bind-parameters

Comment: Prepared statements works with MySQL?

Comment: With all due respect, you should not rely on StackOverflow for reading the documentation for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of steps you need to take to prevent sql injections

- Remove system database priviliges from web user
- Parameterize your input
- Use stored procedures
- clean and validate your input
- protect your error messages

check out this article on the subject

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9378/SQL-Injection-Attacks-and-Some-Tips-on-How-to-Prev

Answer (score 0):

You should use prepared statement on your query. With this method, you will prevent SQL injections.

EDIT:

Here you can find some guide/docs:

[First](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

[Second](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score -1):

1. Create something that is able to report all php errors to your email. You'll be able to find the errors etc way faster and you'll need it to solve problems if there any. (Coding problems are often security problems as well) code box 1 is the code I wrote for [tnhteam.com](http://www.tnhteam.com) to receive error emails. For example call it email-error-handler.php and include it into your site.
2. Visit all pages on your site or scan your site with [Xenu's Link Sleuth (TM)](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) if you have to many pages. and repair all problems, check your email for error messages as well (the first time error messages can go to spam/junk folder and set a folder for error messages)
3. After this you might want to ask [Beyond Security](http://www.beyondsecurity.com/) (Free for 1 domain) to scan your website, they will find all important info and problems regarding your site, fix all they errors they find.
4. Solve the URL injection problem: find code in code box 2, for more info visit the [site](http://www.derby-web-design-agency.co.uk/blog-post/what-is-and-how-to-prevent-url-injections-in-php/11/) where I found the code in code box 2.

I hope this is will help you into the right direction

#### Code Box 1

```
<?php
//===========================================================================\\
//                                                                           \\
// Copyright (c) 2000-2015 Willem Vyent.        All rights reserved.         \\
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------\\
// http://www.tnhteam.com/                http://www.awesomehosting.org/     \\
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------\\
//                                                                           \\
//                                                                           \\
//                                                                           \\
//                                                                           \\
//         Coded by Willem Vyent                                             \\
// This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but       \\
// WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY                                                      \\
//                                                                           \\
//                                                                           \\
//===========================================================================\\
if(!defined('FILE_PROTECT')) { // You should define this in your pages BEFORE you include this file 
   die('This file cannot be accessed directly!<br /><br />Dit bestand kan niet rechtstreeks worden benaderd<br /><br />Click <a href=\'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '>here</a> to visit our homepage'); // Do not change it's a text for users who visit this document. we included a link as well...
}
    // Custom error handler - collecting information
    function awesome_error_handler($number, $message, $file, $line, $vars)

    {
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    $email = "<p>An error known as number <strong>$number</strong> has been found on line <strong>$line</strong>, this error has been found in file <strong>$file</strong>. The requested URL with errors is $actual_link<br /><p> $message </p>";

    $email .= "<pre>" . print_r($vars, 1) . "</pre>";

    $headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "";

    // Email the error to the webmaster...
    error_log($email, 1, 'your-name@example.com', $headers); // Yor email here...

    // Make sure that you decide how to respond to errors (on the user's side)
    // Either echo an error message, or kill the entire project. It's up to you...
    // The code below ensures that we only "die" if the error was more than
    // just a NOTICE.
    if ( ($number !== E_NOTICE) && ($number < 1024) ) {
    die('Sorry, this page is broken, but our coders will fix it ASAP.'); // your message to the website user (visitor)
    }
    }
    // Tell this script to use this error handler when errors found..
    set_error_handler('awesome_error_handler');
    ?>
```

#### Code box 2

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_REQUEST["id"])){

if(!is_int($_REQUEST["id"])){

    //redirect this person back to homepage

 } else {

    $id_raw = trim(htmlentities($_REQUEST["id"]));
    $id_secure = mysql_real_escape_string($id_raw);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM databasetable WHERE id='".$id_secure."'";

 }
}
?>
```